# Serviceからステータスバーを暗くしたい

Tags: android, java

`setStatusBarColor()`を使用してステータスバーを暗くする処理をバックグラウンドで常に行いたいです。

Serviceを継承したクラスでそれを行うと、`getWindow()`でエラーになってしまいます。

Serviceで`getWindow()`を使用する、もしくはServiceで`setStatusBarColor()`を使用する方法を教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

基本的にはできません。

まず、ServiceとはUIを持たないコンポーネントなので、Windowにアタッチされない＝Windowを取得することはできません。

`setStatusBarColor()`というのはAndorid 5.0から追加された比較的新しいAPIになります。これが意図するところは、Lollipop以降のアプリケーションでは、アクションバーやステータスバーの色を利用してアプリのブランディングを行うというものです。それ以前のデザインガイドラインでは、ステータスバーの色は固定で、ブランディングはアプリアイコンをアクションバーに置くことで表現するというものでした。

他のアプリケーションのカラーブランディングを妨害するAPIは恐らく用意されないでしょう。

---

ただし完全に不可能かというとそうでもありません。

`WindowManager`の取得はServiceからでも行えるので、そこに任意のビューを重ねることで、それらしく見せること自体はできると思います。ステータスバーの上へ重ねる指定は、SDKのバージョンによって異なりますが、`setStatusBarColor()`のある5.0以降と考えると、`LayoutParams`に`TYPE_STATUS_BAR_PANEL`で可能だと思います。

これについてはリスクのある手段でもありますので、紹介に留めます。

Comment: もしよろしければ、どのようなリスクがあるのか教えていただきたいです。

Comment: `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW `というちょっと大げさなパーミッション（「画面全体が偽装される」と警告される）が必要なこと、使い方を間違えると表面に追加したビューがタッチイベントを拾って、現在フォアグラウンドにいるアプリを妨害してしまいます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。もう一つ質問させてください。
TYPE_STATUS_BAR_PANELを使用したところ、BadTokenExceptionとなり、permission denied for this window typeと表記され、エラーになりました。
permissionにはSYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOWやINTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOWを追加しましたが、同様のエラーになりました。
もし解決法をお知りでしたら、お願いします。